How do to an Elasticsearch ESQL Distinct Query?
In SQL:
select distinct(session_id) from my_table where userid = '20';

What I have in ESQL:
from my_table | where userid == 20

What should I add in the the next pipe so that it returns the unique session ids from the table? This is the link to the ESQL documentation. Which processing command is to be utilised for this?

not too sure about esql but in plain es queries that would be a terms aggregation on the session_id, with a term query of userid = 20. I can't readily find documentation about aggregations in esql but perhaps you'll have more luck than me.

@FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I know in the Query DSl it would be the terms aggregation. I was trying out this new way of querying and wanted to learn about it.

You can add STATS count(*) BY session_id for distinct(session_id).
#Push the sample data
POST /my_table/_bulk
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "1" } }
{ "session_id": 1, "userid": 20, "other_column": "data1" }
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "2" } }
{ "session_id": 2, "userid": 20, "other_column": "data2" }
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "3" } }
{ "session_id": 1, "userid": 20, "other_column": "data3" }
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "4" } }
{ "session_id": 3, "userid": 30, "other_column": "data4" }
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "5" } }
{ "session_id": 4, "userid": 20, "other_column": "data5" }
{ "index": { "_index": "my_table", "_id": "6" } }
{ "session_id": 2, "userid": 20, "other_column": "data6" }


#with DSL query
POST /my_table/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "query":{"term":{"userid":20}},
  "aggs":{"unique_session_ids":{"terms":{"field":"session_id"}}}
}


#with ESQL query
POST /_query?format=txt
{
  "query": " FROM my_table | WHERE userid == 20 | STATS count(*) BY session_id "
}


Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/esql-rest.html#esql-rest-params
